# Android 12 Splash Api issue

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, splash-screen, android-12

I am using android 12 splash api. When device is rotated app shows white background below status bar. I think it happens because my splash background is white but I don't want to show it when fragment is loaded. How to resolve this issue?

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

**fragment_dashboard:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/logo_blue"
    tools:context=".ui.Dashboard.DashboardFragment">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**DashboardFragment.kt:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

**themes.xml:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AAAAccountsKotlin" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/logo_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/logo_blue</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/logo_blue</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.CustomSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AAAAccountsKotlin</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">3000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Dependency:**

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
```

**Fragment Without Splash Api:**
[image]

**Fragment with Splash Api:**
[image]

**Issue in red:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a setup bit and update your Splash API version to

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0")
```

For Light mode

Create a a folder for light in splash screen

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Splash Screen Theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppSplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/dark</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher_round</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">6000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplishSplash</item>

        <!-- Status bar and Nav bar configs -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/dark</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For Theme.XML

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SplishSplash" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>

        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>

        <!-- Status bar & Nav bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I have tried your answer but still no luck

Comment: I don't know what is causing this

Comment: The splash screen API looks like a mandatory hot mess .. if you can do without one just don't bother ..

Comment: @Mark other approach is that I create a separate splash fragment but I have read it on other answers that splash api is introduced for this purpose and creating separate splash fragment increases app loading time

Comment: The splash screen was added for feature parity with iOS .. there was no depth to Googles' decision other than this.  It has been added hastily, without consultation of developers and focuses on a limited number of fixed use cases that now limits what a splash screen can do - hence if you don't need to actually load anything, don't bother with one .. if you do have to load during a splash screen good luck with all the hot mess in code you'll have to do using the Google api.. whats worse on Android 12+ it'll break your own splash screen .. behaviour

Comment: I actually have to load data on splash. So, I think I need to create a separate fragment for this purpose